# Ubuntu / Unable to use partition / wont show up on lvdisplay, vgdisplay, nor pvdisplay

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I am at a total loss. I have 100G set for my LVM, and have been trying to either expand it or just open up access to the rest of the partition on `/dev/sda3`. It shows up in `lsblk` but doing anything in regards to trying to interact with it has been a dead end. Below I have pasted the outputs from the related commands.

I am a newbie when it comes to managing linux partitions, so references to tutorials on this are appreciated.

From what I can tell, I can expand my LVM volume to use the rest of the partition but attempting to find the references to the LVM to do so are coming up blank as well. Can anyone provide any guidance on this topic?

```
root@LinuxServer:/# lvdisplay
root@LinuxServer:/# vgdisplay
root@LinuxServer:/# pvdisplay
root@LinuxServer:/# pvdisplay -v
root@LinuxServer:/# vgdisplay -v
  No volume groups found.
root@LinuxServer:/# lvdisplay -v
  No volume groups found.
root@LinuxServer:/#
```

```
root@LinuxServer:/# lsblk
...
sda                         8:0    0 930.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0   1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   928G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

GPart Screenshot of the partition:

[image: GPart Screenshot of the partition]

Comment: Do you really want to manage the disk by LVM? This is not necessary except you want to expand the volume over multiple partitions or disks.

Comment: It doesnt really matter to me honestly. I was just trying to be able to use the rest of the storage. Using the LVM seemed like a logical choice since that's where I had a few basic applications installed. If there is another way to do this that works better and/or is easier, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your answer in the upper comments you have no deeper interest in the features of LVM, but just search a solution to access the available storage.

Assuming `/dev/sda` this is your only storage disk in the system and this will stay like this for the lifetime of your installation, the advantages of LVM are less than the disadvantages due to the more complicated handling.
(Surely some people will argue different...)

So my suggestion is not to use LVM but to use the traditional partition sheme:

Rollback your LVM usage by removing the LVM label from `/dev/sda3`. As no *logical volume* and no *volume group* exist removing the physical volume is enough:

```
sudo pvremove -v /dev/sda3
```

---

Re-partition your disk as required for the operation system:

- Linux loves to have a SWAP partition. Using LVM it would have been made available within the LVM. Without LVM this has to be done as a separate physical partition.
  *=> Think about its size: Depending on details typically it is 1x or 2x the size of you RAM + 1x RAM-size extra for the hibernation feature, if you intend to use it.*
- Without LVM you do not need a separate boot partition. But there might be reasons to have one.

To manage this use the tool `fdisk`.

- In the following I assume you keep the boot partition, else you should fist backup any data from it.
- I assume 8 Gigabyte as the intended size of the SWAP partition.
- I assume you intent to create a Linux type filesystem (ext4/xfs/...), here `ext4`.
  For NTFS you should choose "11 - Microsoft basic data".
- If you do not intend to create a SWAP partition, the partitioning need not to change. But you should assure that the partition type of sda3 is set correct, as LVM uses a different type.

```sh
sudo fdisk /dev/sda    # start fdisk

   p                   # Show partitions to get an overview:
                       # Verify "GPT" is the partition scheme.
   d                   # Delete — fdisk will ask for the partition
      3                # Choose sda3, the 100G partition

# Create the Data partition:
   n                   # Create a new partition
      <enter>          # Choose the default partition number
      <enter>          # Choose the default 1st sector of the partition
      -8GiB            # Leave 8 Gigabyte free (example-size of the SWAP partition)
   t                   # Set the type of the partition.
      3                # Select the new large data partition.
      20               # Set to "Linux filesystem" (usually the default)

# Create the SWAP partition:
   n                   # Create a new partition
      <enter>          # Choose the default partition number
      <enter>          # Choose the default 1st sector of the partition
      <enter>          # Use the remaining space. Should be 8 Gigabyte.
   t                   # Set the type of the partition
      4                # Select the 8GiB SWAP partition.
      19               # Set to "Linux SWAP"

# Check and save changes:
   p                   # See the new partition table.
                       # Verify sizes and types are as intended.
   w                   # Write to disk. This exits "fdisk".

# Create the filesystem "ext4" with Label "MyLinux":
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L MyLinux /dev/sda3

# DONE.
# (The SWAP partition does not have a filessystem)
```

Now the partition should be ready to be mounted and used by Linux.

---

As you present your system as having only one storage drive, I'm wondering, why the setup of your Linux distro did not manage this for you. The installation usually relies on a local storage for itself.

If this is just a failed Linux installation perhaps you might want to cleanup the whole disk (with `fdisk`) and restart.